# Merge two dataframe and add new column based on merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe that are sources based on my database and an API response:

```
database_data=[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "user_id": 555,
        "_deleted": True
    },
    {
        "id": 456,
        "user_id": 555,
        "_deleted": True
    }]


api_data = [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "user_id": 555,
        "_deleted": True
    },
    {
        "id": 789,
        "user_id": 555,
        "_deleted": True
    }
]
```

Based on those data, I would like perform a merge between API and database and apply a rule:

- If data exist on database and doesn't exist on API response, I need to add a column df['_deleted'] = True for rows that exists only on database;
- If data exist on both side, column df['_deleted'] should be False for all rows that meets this condition.

I've started to write some code to perform merge but I don't know how to add this conditional column.

```
df_db = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(database_data)
df_api = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(api_data)
# df_api.merge(df_db ... ??)
```

Any advice to solve it?

Comment: What columns are you merging on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` with `indicator=True`, you can then compare the indicator output to get your column.

```
res = df_api.merge(df_db, how='left', indicator='indicator')
res['_deleted'] = res.pop('indicator') != "both"

   _deleted   id  user_id
0     False  123      555
1      True  789      555
```

Answer (score 2):

I will using `merge` with `indicator=True`

```
df_db=df_api.drop('_deleted',1).merge(df_db.drop('_deleted',1) , on = ['id','user_id'],indicator=True,how='right')
df_db['_deleted']=df_db['_merge'].map({'both':False,'right_only':True})

df_db
Out[135]: 
    id  user_id      _merge  _deleted
0  123      555        both     False
1  456      555  right_only      True
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see this when posting mine but it is quite similar so let me know if you want me to remove it.

Comment: @cs95 no worry :-)